# Replace empty values with empty arrays in jq

Tags: jq

I am getting a list of EBS volumes in an AWS account. I need to print out the volume id the size and the time it was attached.

If a volume is not attached, it has an empty value for "attach time". I wold like to replace empty values for attach time with an empty array.

If I try to substitute an empty array, I get this error:

```
cat nonprod-ebs-sanitized.json | jq -r '.Volumes[]  | [ .VolumeId, .Size, (.Attachments[].AttachTime  // [] )] | @csv'

jq: error (at <stdin>:4041): array ([]) is not valid in a csv row
```

If I substitute anything else, like exclamation marks the substitution works:

```
cat nonprod-ebs-sanitized.json | jq -r '.Volumes[]  | [ .VolumeId, .Size, (.Attachments[].AttachTime  // "!!!!!!!" )] | @csv'

"vol-0c21e56a50a1c5009",50,"!!!!!!!"
"vol-0b6d7b1488438cc95",120,"!!!!!!!"
"vol-066e24cb8d2294605",8,"2018-12-11T18:54:26.000Z"
```

How can I get substituting an empty array for empty attach time values to work?

Here is the original json I am working with: [ORIGINAL JSON](https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/431ee7f8f3fa4f3a752c8a1fd0c8e094)

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelies. What output do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not followed the [mcve](/questions/tagged/mcve) guidelines, it’s difficult to ascertain what precisely you want, as “empty array” has no specific meaning in the CSV context, but it would make sense to use `"[]"` instead of `[]` in the expression `// []`